# How to get Terraform azuread_groups to accept UPN instead of object_id?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to use azuread_group to add users to the AAD group by using UPN instead of user object_ID.   Below is what I have:

**Group.json**

```
    [
{
    "team_name": "Test Group1",
    "members": [
        "user1@mydomain.com",
        "user2@mydomain.com"
    ]
},
{
    "team_name": "Test Group2",
    "members": [
        "User3@mydomain.com",
        "User4@mydomain.com"
    ]
}
]
```

**My main.tf**

```
locals {
    team_name_list = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/group.json"))
}

resource "azuread_group" "provision-aad-group" {
  count = length(local.team_name_list)

  display_name              = local.team_name_list[count.index].team_name
  prevent_duplicate_names   = true
  members = var.aad_group_display_name[count.index].members
}
```

Unfortunately, the above TF code complain that the member string needs to be object_id.  Any suggestion on how I can covert the upn into object_id dynamicatlly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use date source [azuread_user](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/user) to get the id based on email.

Comment: Thanks Marcin.  Any suggestion on how to construct the logic to do this on a nested json?